# Why member of enum element can be null in certain devices

Tags: java, android

I'm unable to produce null pointer exception at my side. However, I do receive quite a number of null pointer exception crash report from my users.

```
public static Currency getStockCurrency(PortfolioRealTimeInfo portfolioRealTimeInfo, Code code) {
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    // Get traded currency in this stock code.
    //////////////////////////////////////////
    final Currency stockCurrency;
    org.yccheok.jstock.engine.currency.Currency c = portfolioRealTimeInfo.currencies.get(code);
    if (c == null) {
        Country stockCountry = org.yccheok.jstock.engine.Utils.toCountry(code);
        stockCurrency = stockCountry.stockCurrency;
    } else {
        stockCurrency = c;
    }
    return stockCurrency;
}

public static double getExchangeRate(PortfolioRealTimeInfo portfolioRealTimeInfo, Currency localCurrency, Code code) {
    final Currency stockCurrency = getStockCurrency(portfolioRealTimeInfo, code);

    return getExchangeRate(portfolioRealTimeInfo, localCurrency, stockCurrency);
}

public static double getExchangeRate(PortfolioRealTimeInfo portfolioRealTimeInfo, Currency localCurrency, Currency stockCurrency) {
    // Possible null.
    if (localCurrency == null) {
        if (stockCurrency.toString().equals("GBX")) {
```

NPE happens at line

```
if (stockCurrency.toString().equals("GBX")) {
```

However, I don't understand

1. `stockCurrency` can never be null because
2. `getStockCurrency` can never return null because
3. `stockCurrency = stockCountry.stockCurrency;`. `stockCountry` is not null, as crash doesn't happen at that point. Member of `stockCountry` cannot be null because
4. `stockCountry` is an enum. I don't see any reason why `stockCurrency` can be null : https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/blob/master/src/org/yccheok/jstock/engine/Country.java#L29
5. `Currency.valueOf` can never return null. It may throw exception some how. But, I never receive such exception : https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/blob/master/src/org/yccheok/jstock/engine/currency/Currency.java#L52

Any idea why NPE happens at line

```
if (stockCurrency.toString().equals("GBX")) {
```

### Update

Some devices with Android 5.0 gives better exception info

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at org.yccheok.jstock.portfolio.m.a(SourceFile:244)
at org.yccheok.jstock.portfolio.m.a(SourceFile:272)
at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.portfolio.BuyPortfolioFragment.b(SourceFile:206)
at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.portfolio.BuyPortfolioFragment.b(SourceFile:314)
at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.portfolio.BuyPortfolioFragment.h(SourceFile:841)
at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.portfolio.BuyPortfolioFragment.a(SourceFile:793)
at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.portfolio.fd.a(SourceFile:521)
at org.yccheok.jstock.gui.portfolio.fd.onLoadFinished(SourceFile:488)
at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(SourceFile:427)
at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(SourceFile:395)
at android.support.v4.a.o.b(SourceFile:104)
at android.support.v4.a.a.b(SourceFile:223)
at android.support.v4.a.b.a(SourceFile:61)
at android.support.v4.a.q.e(SourceFile:461)
at android.support.v4.a.q.c(SourceFile:47)
at android.support.v4.a.w.handleMessage(SourceFile:474)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

It seems that `stockCurrency.toString()` is executed successfully, but it returns null. But, it seems weird to me still, as `stockCurrency.toString()` shouldn't suppose return null. (This is because `Currency`'s `valueOf` factory method doesn't accept null value)

*p/s I'm using ProGuard. However, I can't imagine how it contributes to this mystery crash.*

*p/s/s Possible the app confuses my custom made `Currency` to standard `java.util.Currency`?*

Comment: Does your stack trace really show the crash in that line? Equals could be called in other occasions, not necessarily on the line you specified.

Comment: I don't see anything.  But I'm wondering: why do you call `java.util.Currency.getInstance` and throw away the result (in your `Currency` class)?

Comment: @ajb It is way to verify, the passed in currency code is a valid currency code (with exception on "GBX", where we return in early before calling `java.util.Currency.getInstance`)

Comment: Have you tried it without obfuscation? Did it have the same error?

Comment: @Android777 I can't. This problem only occur for *some* end users. I need to ensure my code is obfuscated, before releasing to end users.

Comment: Hmm, this one I didn't get. What prevents you from launching it without obfuscation so we can scratch this reason out of consideration? Not related, but why would you need obfuscation while uploading all your sources to the public repository?

Comment: The Mobile app project (Android) itself is a closed source product. That's why I need obfuscation to protect the entire source code. The code I post in github, is for Desktop app product. Both of them share the certain amount of same code base.

Comment: Ok, makes sense :) What about testing it with disabled obfuscation for the sake of figuring out the reason?

Comment: @Android777 Not able to produce the crash outcome, by testing internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this problem is that, the creation of `Currency` object isn't done through normal constructor or factory method.

It is being done through Gson serialization.

Here's the factors which contributes to this weird behavior

1. The legacy json string, is generated from obfuscated `Currency` class.
2. In new version, we decide not to obfuscate `Currency` class.

Hence, if we perform de-serialization for [PortfolioRealTimeInfo](https://github.com/yccheok/jstock/blob/master/src/org/yccheok/jstock/portfolio/PortfolioRealTimeInfo.java#L124) via the following string

```
String data = "{\"currencies\":[[{\"code\":\"4677.KL\"},{\"a\":\"MYR\"}],[{\"code\":\"5247.KL\"},{\"a\":\"MYR\"}],[{\"code\":\"5183.KL\"},{\"a\":\"MYR\"}],[{\"code\":\"6947.KL\"},{\"a\":\"MYR\"}],[{\"code\":\"6742.KL\"},{\"a\":\"MYR\"}]],\"stockPrices\":[[{\"code\":\"4677.KL\"},1.67],[{\"code\":\"5247.KL\"},3.18],[{\"code\":\"6947.KL\"},6.04]],\"exchangeRates\":{},\"exchangeRatesTimestamp\":0,\"stockPricesTimestamp\":1430906678615}";
```

We will fail.

Take note, for `{\"a\":\"MYR\"}`, the `a` is the result of obfuscated of `Currency`'s `currency` member.

When we decide not to obfuscated `Currency`, with such, Gson will "help" us to create a none-null `Currency` object, with its member variable `currency` is null.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but I think it's because on this line:

```
UnitedKingdom("/images/16x16/gb.png", "United Kingdom", Currency.newInstance("GBX"), Currency.newInstance("GBP")),
```

This should be

```
UnitedKingdom("/images/16x16/gb.png", "United Kingdom", Currency.newInstance("GBP"), Currency.newInstance("GBP")),
```

And probably this

```
if (stockCurrency.toString().equals("GBX")) {
```

Should be this

```
if (stockCurrency.toString().equals("GBP")) {
```

But even if not, I think you should make an `enum` for the currencies,and specify them manually (for example in a `static {}` initializer block, rather than with reflection.

Comment: Using GBX (This is not standard ISO code) is by intention. That's why I need to have a custom made Currency class, to accept GBX.

Comment: I see. But according to this error, maybe it is explicitly the `GBX` one that doesn't work, so you should test that to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

the string that is return by the stockCurrency.toString() method returns null, try for example to add an if condition to make sure it's not null, or if you are using some logging mechanism try to log the string value that should be returned by the toString() method before doing the return and you'd find it returning null. then from there you can start your debugging.